# Trying to assign a pointer of the same type says Type mismatch in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I have two different variables defined as `^Byte` as in:

```
var 
  P1 : ^Byte;
  P2 : ^Byte;
```

Yet when I I try:

```
P1:=P2;
```

it says Type mismatch yet I can do:

```
P1:=Pointer(P2);
```

Coming from C, I don't get it?  Wouldn't `P1` and `P2` be the value of the pointer and when you want to access what it points to you would use `P1^` and `P2^` and if you use `@P1` or `@P2` you are getting the address to the pointer variable itself?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik in classic (70's) standard pascal this should work. But Turbo Pascal adn Delphi and derivatives went a different route, and consider both ^byte's declaration of new separate types.

Solution:  declare pbyte = ^byte; and use pbyte everywhere. If you are using a recent Delphi or Free Pascal, pbyte is already predefined or in unit types.

Comment: Interestingly I could define `pbyte = ^byte;` in the two separate modules and it's happy with it as well. ?

Comment: Btw, "pointer" in Turbo and Delphi dialects accepts all pointer types. It is a kind of catchall.